# Unable to start service on VMware Workstation 11

Tags: networking, vmware

I am trying to install vmware workstation 11 on Ubuntu 15.04 and I get this error:

> Unable to start services "virtual network devices"

How do I fix it?

[image: see log file for details]

Answer (score 1):

Enter these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl http://pastie.org/pastes/9934018/download -o /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
sudo tar -xf vmnet.tar
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
sudo mv vmnet.tar vmnet.tar.SAVED
sudo tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
sudo rm -r vmnet-only
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Comment: Can you please say what the file was? The link is not working anymore, also it's better if the file can be downloaded from a trustworthy source